# python and pip install (pygame)

Tags: python, pip, pygame, pycharm

I am trying to install python from python.org and I also downloaded pip. To check that it downloaded properly, I booted up terminal to see if it could find the command. I did python3 -V and pip3 -V (which came up with the correct versions) which loaded fine but then tried 'pip install pygame' to download pygame as I am trying to make a chess game through python and it said that the command pip wasn't found. I am trying to follow a YouTube tutorial to download PIP and python and in the video 'pip install pygame' worked for him and it did not for me. How do I get terminal to recognise pip. I am coding with pycharm.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326569/under-what-circumstances-may-i-add-urgent-or-other-similar-phrases-to-my-quest

Comment: if i am not wrong for python 3, the pip should be is pip3.
so the command should be : pip3 install ....

Comment: Read [Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Remove the screenshots and past the error trace in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use pip3 instead of pip can solve it. Your shell cannot find pip, so can you make sure where the pip executable file? If you can, please add it into your $PATH.